# What does Tony Stark shout in the Captain America: Civil War trailer?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america, captain-america-civil-war

At the end of the latest trailer for Captain America: Civil War (as of March 20th), just before someone jumps in and separates Cap from his shield, Tony shouts something to signal this person. Can anyone clarify what Tony says, and what it means?

Comment: _Underoos._ Which means a funny under clothing containing pictures, graphics of cartoons character(s). There are Spider-Man printed undergarments such as in the example of Stark07's answer. I'm not sure if this counts as breaking the 4th wall. Or he was just making fun of his tight suit.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> He shouts "Underoos", a reference to: 
>  [image]

Comment: How to add an image under the spoiler tag? If someone can edit I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: how did you make it so it hides the words

Comment: Now I’ve seen this, I can’t unhear the phrase, but before I was convinced he actually said “on the roof”.

Comment: @alexwlchan So was I. That's why I asked this question :-)

Comment: Thanks @phantom42. I had tried doing it that way but for some reason hadn't worked when I did it.

Comment: @sluger Prepend `>!` to the text on its line. Like so: `>! Spiderman Underwear` (obviously, it doesn't work in comments, much less inside `backticks`)

Comment: How do you know it's a reference to those, and not just how Spider-Man's costume looks like underwear?

Comment: I wonder why people keep downvoting this answer... Anyhow. Their choice.

Comment: @RogueJedi I think the picture was an example, it is not necessary to the answer which particular set of underoos.   Even if here are none in universe with that particular character on them, it's a fun dig both on the fact that the costume looks like underwear *and* on the relative youth of the target of the remark (since underoos are designed mostly for kids and Charlie's Angels.)

Answer (score -1):

He isn't "known" to be Peter Parker so he can't call him pete right? Stark doesn't call him spiderman as that would be lame and not in the slightest bit sarcastic (which is RDJ's Stark to a tee) so he mocks him for being young  (in an affectionate mentor kind of way) and stark made the suit purposefully tight to help with friction and wind resistance... it still just looks like a onesie so he calls him underoos as Peter wouldn't get insulted not knowing what they are
..  simple really