# Does Tony Stark break the 4th wall by calling Spider-Man "Underoos" in Civil War trailer?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, captain-america-civil-war

In [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/122602/62088), it says there is a reference to Spider-Man undergarments in Captain America: Civil War trailer.

Are these undergarments (the Spider-Man ones in the answer I shared above) specific to Marvel Universe (known in Marvel comics or movies) or Robert Downey Jr. made a reference to the real world product by calling it in the trailer? *Is this a 4th wall thing?*

<sub>I know that these undergarments can exist in any universe. These are undergarments for pity's sake... Please be productive with your comments and answers and avoid commenting on *obvious* things.</sub>

Comment: I'd say it's just a joke pertaining to how Spider-Man's outfit resembles underwear, in universe.

Comment: @RogueJedi I thought that as well until I saw that answer. I was wondering if that was the case instead of simple calling-names-Tony. It's known that he does call others with funny names.

Comment: I for one disagree with that answer. Either he called him something besides "underoos" or he said "underoos" because of Spider-Man's costume.

Comment: If that's another word, must be really similar to "underoos" because most of the internet says he calls him "underoos." Other than that, latter part in your comment is probable.

Comment: If you think about, overt costumes aren't seen much in the MCU. Tony's wearing power armor, Thor's wearing his normal clothes, the Hulk is wearing what's left of his normal clothes, etc. The next closest thing would be Captain America's suit, which is still more of a combat suit. Spider-man is the only superhero we've seen in Spandex. So, I think the Underoos comment was probably warranted, in-universe.

Comment: @JohnSensebe I think that's true. Tony calls Thor "Point-Break" by referenceing to a real movie. Most of the things and terms in MCU are real things that we have in real life. Tony probably chose this word to call Spider-Man because his spandex resembles... _underoos._

Comment: @apollo, Indeed. We know that the MCU has *Galaga*, for a non-clothing-related example.

Comment: @JohnSensebe _Yes._ MCU has lots of things like that. I'm not stating that Tony was referring to the Spider-Man underoos. I'm simply asking if the answer that I posted with the question (the item in it) is known in MCU as well or Tony was just calling him that by making fun of Spider-Man's spandex. I would say the latter but an answer already shared a Spider-Man underoos image to explain Tony's behaviour in the trailer.

Comment: I could be wrong (when has *that* ever happened? ) but in order to break the forth wall, doesn't the character need to have an aside with the audience?  IMO, calling another character names doesn't dovetail with the breaking of the forth wall.

Comment: @MajorStackings It mostly means a character is aware of the fictional nature. It doesn't require the audience some times. My question refers to another answer. If that is a reliable answer, then Tony used something that exists in this universe (an underoos with Spider-Man print on it) and called Spider-Man "underoos." Most possibly he meant his spandex suit while calling him "underoos," I just wanted to know if there was a connection.

Answer (score 12):

It's very unlikely he's breaking the fourth wall.

While we don't know for sure if underoos exist in the MCU, there are no real reasons why they shouldn't, given that other real-world products such as Burger King and Apple exist in the MCU.

In real life, there are underoos based off other non-Marvel properties, such as *Star Wars*, which we know exists in the MCU.

[image: Star Wars underooes]
[image: Steve's list]

> Spider-Man: Hey guys, you ever see that really old movie, *Empire Strikes Back*?

As you can see, they sort of resemble Spider-Man's costume, so if Tony did in fact say "underoos" it was probably because of that.

Comment: So we are connecting the dots in here. Star Wars universe exists in MCU. We have SW underoos in real life, so underoos exists in MCU as well. I'd say we didn't need that sort of indirect pointing but it looks too good to say so. What I'm looking for is comics references as well. (I didn't downvote btw.)

Comment: Oracle exists in the MCU as well. :/   Also, Elon Musk's company's exists, but SpaceX is really Hammer Industries.

Comment: There's no reason the MCU Underoos company could not have super-hero underwear outfits already of the Avengers and other real (to the MCU) costumed heroes.  Iron Man and Captain America especially would be good, highly recognizable patterns to put on underwear.